# PHP grouping array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i've got the following array:

```
$comments   = array();
$comments[] = array('member_id' => '17',
                    'time'      => '2011-05-10 11:10:00',
                    'name'      => 'John Smith',
                    'comment'   => 'Test Comment 1');
$comments[] = array('member_id' => '25',
                    'time'      => '2011-05-10 11:26:00',
                    'name'      => 'David Jones',
                    'comment'   => 'Test Comment 2');
$comments[] = array('member_id' => '17',
                    'time'      => '2011-05-10 13:15:00',
                    'name'      => 'John Smith',
                    'comment'   => 'Test Comment 3');
```

How would i go about grouping it by `member_id`? So I'll be able to display the comments on the page with the following formatting:
John Smith(2 comments)

- 2011-05-10 11:10:00 | Test Comment 1
- 2011-05-10 13:15:00 | Test Comment 3

David Jones(1 comment)

- 2011-05-10 11:26:00 | Test Comment 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to sort them by the name field (check out [usort](http://php.net/usort) for that), but even easier might be to just populate a new array in this way:

```
$grouped = array();
foreach($comments as $c) {
  if(!isset($grouped[$c['name']]) {
    $grouped[$c['name']] = array();
  }

  $grouped[$c['name']][] = $c;
}

//Now it's just a matter of a double foreach to print them out:
foreach($grouped as $name => $group) {
  //print header here
  echo $name, "<br>\n";

  foreach($group as $c) {
    //print each comment here
  }
}
```

Comment: Also note that you can get the comments sorted by the author's name using ksort after the first foreach loop.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using a second grouping array

```
$groups[] = array();
foreach( $comment as $k=>$v ) {
    $groups[$v['member_id']][] = $k
}
```

And then to print it

```
foreach( $group as $m_id=>$arr ) {
    echo "Group $m_id<br/>\n";
    foreach( $arr as $k ) {
        echo $comment[$k]."<br/>\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try with taking multi-dimensional array.

```
 $comment_groups[] = array();
    $m_id = '';

    foreach( $comment_groups as $key=>$val ) {
         if($key == 'member_id'){
             $m_id = $val;
            }
           $comment_groups[$m_id]][] = $val;
   }
```

Then you can print as you want to display.